# Move to the middle of a block code

Tags: c++, vim, vi

Using Vim I'm trying to move the cursor in the middle of a code block, but I can't figure out how to do this :

```
//cursor is for instance here.

{
    //or here

    //some code
    // .... **** move cursor here ****
    //some more code 

}
```

The final idea is to have a shortcut that saves the current position, moves the cursor in the middle of the code block, sets the current line to the middle of the screen (with the shortcut "zz"), and then moves back to the saved position.

I'd prefer a built-in vim function, but a plugin works too.

EDIT: This is for c++ and so I want it for brackets {}.

Comment: pls define "middle of a code block"

Comment: Do you want a language agnostic solution? Or something that uses `{}` as "markers? What did you try?

Comment: Sorry I forgot that, I edited the question.

Comment: Be careful with the shortcut 'zz', 'ZZ' is the same as ':wq' so you could easily quit vim if you had capslock enabled.

Comment: Didn't know about the ZZ, good to know !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I gave it a (quick and dirty) go:

```
function! Middleize()

  " use ]M to jump to either the end of the current method if we are in it
  " or the start of the next method if we are above the method
  normal! ]M

  " we record the current line number
  let first_line = line('.')

  " we go to the other end of the method
  normal! %

  " we record the current line number
  let second_line = line('.')

  " we started either from the top or from the bottom of the method
  " so we have to take that into account when calculating the number
  " of the line we want to jump to
  if first_line < second_line
    let middle_line = first_line + ((second_line - first_line) / 2)
  else
    let middle_line = ((first_line - second_line) / 2) + second_line
  endif

  " let's go!
  execute "normal! " . middle_line . "Gzz"
endfunction

nnoremap <F5> :call Middleize()<CR>
```

Comment: I think that might be the answer.
I was also going for a solution like that, but I miss vim knowledge to write it, so thanks a lot ! I try it, and customize it a bit. Thanks man :)

Answer (score 1):

More of a general solution but might be useful - the [easy-motion](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion) plugin allows you to jump all over the place with great precision.

For example:

[image: initial state]

`<Leader><Leader>w` (default) - '[word motion](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion#usage-example)'

[image: word motion enabled]

`g`

[image: cursor in the middle]

Then to jump back, you'd just do the same thing backwards (in this case, `<Leader><Leader>b g`.

This doesn't set the current line to the middle of the screen, although you can `:set scrolloff=9999` to have the middle of the screen follow your cursor around.

Comment: Not exactly what I want but this is interesting ! This might be enough for me, I'll give it a try !

Answer (score 0):

This won't give you exactly what you want, but it'll get text of the function on the screen (assuming it's not too long).

1. <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> - set a mark at the current cursor position.
2. Repeatedly press <kbd>}</kbd> (jump ahead by a paragraph) until you can see the code you want.
3. <kbd>`</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> - return to the mark you set.

A "paragraph" in vim terms is a group of consecutive non-blank lines.  It's a nice approximation for a block of code.  Also note that you can use any letter for the mark command, so there can be up to 52 of them active at once.

Comment: Thank for your response but it's not really what I was looking for :/ romainl aswered my question, check it.